# Wordpress - post edit Custom Metabox with post search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've impletend this code that creates a custom metabox to choose a related article for a specific post type. It creates a list of 1000 articles to choose from.

Since I have a lot of articles I would like to replace the list with the same search form wp uses in nav-menus edit page (wp-admin/nav-menus.php), where I can search trough pages and click on a checkbox to select the page to link. 
 Here is my code:

```
// Add the Meta Box

function add_related_article_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'related_article_meta_box', // $id
        'Related Article', // $title
        'show_related_article_meta_box', // $callback
        'wpdmpro', // $post type
        'side', // $position
        'high'); // $priority
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_related_article_meta_box');

// Array field
$prefix = 'related_article_';
$custom_meta_fields = array(


    array(
        'label' => 'Post List',
        'desc'  => 'Select your article',
        'id'    =>  $prefix.'post_id',
        'type'  => 'post_list',
        'post_type' => array('post')
    )

);

// Callback
function show_related_article_meta_box() {
    global $custom_meta_fields, $post;
    // nonce verify
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="related_article_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

// form table start and loop
echo '<table class="form-table">';
foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
    // get filed value if exists
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
    // table tr start
    echo '<tr>
            <td>';
    switch($field['type']) {

        // Post List
        case 'post_list':
            $items = get_posts( array (
            'post_type' => $field['post_type'],
            'posts_per_page' => 1000
            ));
            echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">
                            <option value="">Select</option>'; // Post Select
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $custom_post_date = date_i18n( 'd-m-Y', strtotime($item->post_date));
                echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>' .$custom_post_date. '- ' .$item->post_title.'</option>';
            } // end foreach
            echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
            break;


    } //end switch
    echo '</td></tr>';
} //  end foreach
echo '</table>'; // end tabella
}


// Save data
function save_custom_meta($post_id) {
    global $custom_meta_fields;

    // verifica nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['related_article_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;
        // check autosave
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
            return $post_id;
            // check permessions
            if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
                if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
                    return $post_id;
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
                return $post_id;
            }

            // loop into fields and save 
            foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
                $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
                $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
                if ($new && $new != $old) {
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
                } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
                    delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
                }
            } // end foreach

            // save taxonomies
            $post = get_post($post_id);
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $category, 'category' );
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta');
```

Any hint on how to edit callback function (and save data function) in order to get this kind of result would be appreciated.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you talking about Select2.js?  It's basically a `<select>` input but instead of having a pre-coded list it uses AJAX to run a search query.  I use the functionality regularly, I think this is where I got my initial start: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/select2-for-metaboxes-with-ajax.html

I can post an answer if that's not sufficient.